# Which version of flash is required for animation created with ffmpeg?

Tags: flash, ffmpeg, swf, version

I just created a simple flash animation (as swf file) using a series of images and ffmpeg. How can I find out which version of flash it requires? Do I have to test that manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I found out, sorry. You can use swfdump (on linux at least) to get the version info. It happens to be version 6.